# MySQL join another table value based on 2 different tables matching value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

The intended result is 12(price) and pic.png(profilepic). Is this possible to join jobs and profile based on the matching job_id's (jobs+offers), which have matching user id's between profile and offers, all based upon the $_SESSION[user_id]?

```
       Jobs                          Offers                Profile
user_id | job_id | price |    | user_id | job_id |   |user_id | profilepic |
   1    |   1    |   12  |    |    4    |    1   |   |   4    |   pic.png  |
--------------------------    --------------------   -----------------------
$sql="SELECT
      j.price,
      p.profilepic
      FROM Jobs j
      INNER JOIN Offers o  ON o.job_id = j.job_id
      INNER JOIN Profile p ON o.user_id = p.user_id
      WHERE user_id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($price,$profilepic);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Its not working, is it possible?

Comment: what you mean with "its not working"? What you get?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks quite fine. You would just need to qualify column `user_id` in the `from` clause with the table it belongs to:

```
SELECT j.price, p.profilepic
FROM Jobs j
INNER JOIN Offers o  ON o.job_id = j.job_id
INNER JOIN Profile p ON o.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE p.user_id = ?  -- or j.user_id = ?
```

Comment: i cant get the profilepic from the jobs table because the user ID is different between the one who created the job, vs the one who made the offer

Comment: @markusman: ah yes, my bad, I overlooked that. I just changed my answer.

Comment: thank you, it works, just one small adjustment, the `WHERE p.user_id` should be `j.user_id` since it is the jobs table we are basing off of. my mistake for not putting that in there initially. thanks though!

Comment: @markusman: yes, I was wondering, but could not tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't like that you have two identical columns named `userid`.
So simply choose one for the where clause

```
$sql="SELECT
       j.price,
      p.profilepic
      FROM Jobs j
      INNER JOIN Offers o  ON o.job_id = j.job_id
      INNER JOIN Profile p ON o.user_id = p.user_id
      WHERE j.user_id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($price,$profilepic);
$stmt->fetch();
```

See example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/6